# Replacement for linker sections in pure C

Tags: c, linux, linker, cross-platform

I am sorry if the title of this post is not perfectly suitable for what will follow.

In my current project, I have different `.c` files (ie. `*controller_1.c*`, `controller_2.c` and `main.c`). Each "controller" file uses a macro to define a "controller" structure. This structure will end up in a particular section inside my final executable. Here is the macro:

```
#define CONTROLLER_START(_name)                       \
    static struct controller controller_##_name       \
    __attribute__((                                   \
    __used__,                                         \
    __section__("controllers"),                       \
    __aligned__(__alignof__(struct controller)))) = { \
    .name = #_name,
    #define CONTROLLER_END,                           \
};
```

This nice trick (used in the Linux kernel) allows me to compile my project and "discover" different controllers at run-time. I simply have to point to the beginning of this controller section and cycle through all of them. The problem I am running into is that even though this works under Linux, Windows and OSX, this technique is hard or impossible to implement on other operating systems (or through Emscripten which I tried).

I would like to re-implement this portion without using linker scripts at all. The goal is to avoid having to to use ex terns in the `.c` file where I parse these structures and of course avoid includes as well (I can have hundreds of these controller files). I am unsure whether this is feasible but some people on stack overflow may know of a similar trick which is more portable.

Thank you!

Comment: If you can use C++, you may use constructors to register your controllers during start-up. You can also do that in C if you use 'constructor' function attribute in GCC

Comment: @dsi: While it may work, that's a really ugly "solution". It's replacing what's fundamentally constant tables with global state. And of course there are all sorts of nasty issues like the fact that other ctors could run before some or all of the registration ctors have run.

Comment: @R.. you can use constructors to register (insert) the controller into a linked list (i.e have a global pointer to the first one). The order doesn't really matter. The actual processing would be done later inside main() for example, and before that these controllers shouldn't be used at all anyway. I see your point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: you can't. That's why the linux kernel and other projects use this section trick. You can use a compiler extensions like constructors. Or you can fix up the section trick to work on most operating systems. But there's no way to do this in pure C.

I have a hack [on github](https://github.com/art4711/stuff/blob/master/linker_set/linker_set.h) for setting up sections that used to work with MacOS and most unix-like systems with both ELF and a.out. But that's the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I already have this working under OSX, Linux and Windows. I'm interested in Emscripten and mobile OS'es (mainly Android and iOS). Would the constructor attribute work for such targets?

Comment: @user1995488 it should work (it definitely will work with C++ constructors, probably C too). Obviously another option is to write a tool (e.g a script) which would enumerate all of your controllers to a C file containing an array of pointers, which you would then access as-is from your main program.

Comment: I thought about the script as well, or even patching the source as well but it's clearly too hacky for my taste. Thank you for your feedback everyone!